# Displaying tabs and a progress throbber on an ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

My app is using an action bar (through actionbarsherlock) and some screens are using tabbed navigation. An indeterminate progress bar is shown on the far right of the action bar while loading data and is hidden when loading is complete. This causes the tabs (which appear to fill the available space) to expand when the loading is completed. This makes the action bar look like it's jumping.

I've tried giving the tabs a fixed width and setting their weight to `@null` but that doesn't appear to affect anything.

Does anyone have any idea of how to avoid making these tabs grow when the progress bar is hidden? Or is there an established alternative that avoids putting the progress bar in the action bar? Thanks.